# Android - add Bar made in XML for items

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button

I have an Activity, where Items should be added and I made a bar, which should be added for every item we have in this Activity.

This bar contains 4 Symbols (you can share, report, like and play a Soundfile)

For example the playSound-Button:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_play_32"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now heres my XML for the Activity, I included the bar 2 times, but my problem is, that I'm not able to click the second play button:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/babbel_darkgreen"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <!-- Header einbinden -->
    <include layout="@layout/header" />
    <!--## Header einbinden -->

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView_dialectWordResult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/babbel_lightgreen" />

    </ScrollView>

    <include
    layout="@layout/activity_dialect_word_result_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></include>

    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_dialect_word_result_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></include>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I add the bar automatically for every Item added?

Further: How can I address the second button(or 3rd, 4th and so on)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please attach an screenshot. It would be easier to understand the problem.

Comment: @qmar - Sure, here we go: 
[xml-design](http://prntscr.com/96sup8)

So  I want this whole bar to be added, after an Item is added to the List. I tryd to add the bar manually, to test different things, but since the button has the same id, it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you always want exactly 4 of these buttons?

Comment: @JimRhodes - yes!

Item
ButtonBar
Item
ButtonBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use include. Create a style for the button instead.

```
<style name="PlaySoundButton">
  <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/icon_play_32</item>
  <item name="android:layout_gravity">right</item>
  <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
  <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
  <item name="android:layout_alignParentEnd">true</item>
</style>
```

The activity layout could then look something like this. You can also create a style for the bar layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/babbel_darkgreen"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:weightSum="1">
  <!-- Header einbinden -->
  <include layout="@layout/header" />
  <!--## Header einbinden -->
  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top">
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView_dialectWordResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/babbel_lightgreen" />
  </ScrollView>
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <ImageButton
        style="@style/PlaySoundButton"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1" />
  </RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <ImageButton
        style="@style/PlaySoundButton"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2" />
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I will give it a try, when I am home! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to implement a list functionality in a static way. Unfortunately it is not going to work. The solution for this would be to add a list and add a click listener for buttons in each list item.